# Deconstruct Excel Formula To Get Result Without Trying Values

Tags: excel, formula

I need to deconstruct Excel formulas so that I don't have to put values in to see what the result is. I want to put in a result and get a values. I know this is difficult given with multiple variables the answer could be different. I'm looking for more of a theory or method to use to so that I don't have to hunt and peck for answers.

This is my simplified sheet.

```
   A        B       C    Formula for column C
(Row 1)     25     10   (=IF(B1<15,5,10))
(Row 2)     15     22   (=ROUND((AVERAGE(B1:B3)),0))
(Row 3)     25     18   (=ROUND(((B3*5)/7),0))
Total              50   (=SUM(C1:C3))
```

For example, I want to come out with a total of 48. How would I go about working backwards so I didn't have to put a different number in column B to try and get the answer I am looking for, in this case, 48?

Comment: Have you tried highlighting the value you need to work out and pressing F9?

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't do anything. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: The What If Solver may work out. The spreadsheet is MUCH more complex. (It calculates credit score based on quite a few characteristics) but this should get me going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried Goal Seek, the disadvantage is it will only change 1 cell.
Using the Solver will change all three cells, but you then need to set constraints on the cells in column B.